# An example for a function that is defined in $[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and is integrable but is not monotone and not continuous in $[0,1]$

Tags: integration, analysis, continuity, monotone-functions

Basically I have been trying this question for a while but having the function defined as non - monotone and non continuous always messes up my examples.

Comment: Take any continuous function and add a jump discontinuity.

Comment: Are you referring to Lebesgue or Riemann integrability?

Comment: It is not written what integrability but I assume its Riemann since we didn't study Lebesgue yet

Comment: Most functions integrable on $[0,1]$ are neither monotone nor continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take$$\begin{array}{ccc}[0,1]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\t&\mapsto&\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }t\neq\frac12\\1&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$